# Why can I add a String and a reference, but not two Strings? (E0308: Mismatched types)

Tags: string, rust, reference

I'm trying to write a trait on the `String` type that will allow it to concatenate `Bar` to any other string.

I know what the solution is but I'm not sure why it works. Could someone please explain the theory underlying the syntax for me?

```
// problematic code
// error[E0308]: mismatched types
// rustc --explain E0308
fn append_bar(self) -> String {
  self + String::from("Bar")
}

// solution
fn append_bar(self) -> String {
  self + &String::from("Bar")
}
```

The full script is below.

```
trait AppendBar {
    fn append_bar(self) -> String;
}

impl AppendBar for String {
    fn append_bar(self) -> String {
      self + String::from("Bar")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = String::from("Foo");
    let s = s.append_bar();
    println!("s: {}", s);
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn is_FooBar() {
        assert_eq!(String::from("Foo").append_bar(), String::from("FooBar"));
    }

    #[test]
    fn is_BarBar() {
        assert_eq!(
            String::from("").append_bar().append_bar(),
            String::from("BarBar")
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` operator is sugar for the `add` method of the `std::ops::Add` trait, and [the implementation for `String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-Add%3C%26%27_%20str%3E) is:

```
impl<'_> Add<&'_ str> for String {
    type Output = String;

    fn add(mut self, other: &str) -> String {
        self.push_str(other);
        self
    }
}
```

That is, the right hand side of the `+` must be `&str` when the left hand side is a `String`.

However, due to [deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods) for function arguments, you can also pass a `&String` instead of a `&str`, because `String` implements `Deref<Target = str>`.

It's worth noting that a better "fix" for the exact code you provided is to avoid allocating a temporary `String` altogether, since `"Bar"` is already a `&str`:

```
fn append_bar(self) -> String {
    self + "Bar"
}
```

---

See also: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-o)